# Importing XML to Excel to emulate "dragging" an XML document into Excel

Tags: java, xml

I am attempting to programmatically emulate the resulting spreadsheet of a user dragging an XML file into an Excel worksheet. When opening a blank excel and dragging an XML file into it, I get a prompt so I choose ”Open as XML Table”.

Clicking OK then tells me that Excel will create a schema based on the XML file.

Excel will then display all of the attributes and nested items quite nicely with respective headers.

The reason I wanted to go down this generic path is that the contents of the XML file that will be converted is unknown/inconsistent, and letting Excel handle it (quite nicely as it turns out) will be infinitely easier than trying to specifically code for every possible scenario. I am not 100% clear on what Excel is doing with the XML “behind the scenes”, so perhaps if I could work this out I may be able to target that specific function.

I have looked over ApachePOI and all of the examples I have been able to find seem to involve me knowing the XML structure beforehand and programmatically looping over each node/attribute, which I do not. Of course i could also loop over every node/element/attribute in each file and try to parse it that way, but i was hoping there is an easier way to just send the XML to Excel and let it handle it like it does when i drag-and-drop.

Any tips? Even creating a csv rather an xlsx is fine.

Comment: It does do the same as the drag-and-drop in that it gets me to the point of having to options to choose in the popups in excel. now if only i could ALSO pass answers to those options from a command line i would have a workable solution....

Comment: Look at [theese](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6?ocmsassetID=HA010158030&CorrelationId=5d14c3ce-7d4b-4db9-a27a-49a0028b8fc8&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) [links](https://superuser.com/q/189663/100382).

Comment: @madhead Thanks i did look through some of the switches and couldn't find one that seemed to do what i needed. Then i found an article that did it in c# which got me some of the way there:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57364449/importing-xml-to-excel-to-emulate-dragging-an-xml-document-into-excel

I used that to see if i could have c# as a middle-man, but that still threw one popup. Then it dawned on me that there is no guarantee that the user would have excel on their machine so i cannot really involve excel in the creation of the file.